# Send Meeting invite to outlook room using php

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, outlook-restapi, outlook-calendar

The idea is to send a email via PHP mailer to office365 Room email ID with meeting start time and end time, now once the meeting request is accepted by the Microsoft exchange, I need to see that in room calendar in my outlook.

I already tried an approach with Icalendar, here is the ics format which i'm sending through php.

```
'PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 10.0 MIMEDIR//EN' . "\r\n" .
'VERSION:2.0' . "\r\n" .
'METHOD:REQUEST' . "\r\n" .
'BEGIN:VTIMEZONE' . "\r\n" .
'TZID:Eastern Time' . "\r\n" .
'BEGIN:STANDARD' . "\r\n" .
'DTSTART:20091101T020000' . "\r\n" .
'RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=1SU;BYMONTH=11' . "\r\n" .
'TZOFFSETFROM:-0400' . "\r\n" .
'TZOFFSETTO:-0500' . "\r\n" .
'TZNAME:EST' . "\r\n" .
'DTSTART:20090301T020000' . "\r\n" .
'RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=2SU;BYMONTH=3' . "\r\n" .
'TZOFFSETFROM:-0500' . "\r\n" .
'TZOFFSETTO:-0400' . "\r\n" .
'TZNAME:EDST' . "\r\n" .
'BEGIN:VEVENT' . "\r\n" .
'ORGANIZER;CN="'.$from_name.'":MAILTO:'.$from_address. "\r\n" .
'ATTENDEE;CN="'.$to_name.'";ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:'.$to_address. "\r\n" .
'LAST-MODIFIED:' . date("Ymd\TGis") . "\r\n" .
'UID:'.date("Ymd\TGis", strtotime($startTime)).rand()."@".$domain."\r\n" .
'DTSTAMP:'.date("Ymd\TGis"). "\r\n" .
'DTSTART;TZID="Pacific Daylight":'.date("Ymd\THis", strtotime($startTime)). "\r\n" .
'DTEND;TZID="Pacific Daylight":'.date("Ymd\THis", strtotime($endTime)). "\r\n" .
'TRANSP:OPAQUE'. "\r\n" .
'SEQUENCE:1'. "\r\n" .
'SUMMARY:' . $subject . "\r\n" .
'LOCATION:' . $location . "\r\n" .
'CLASS:PUBLIC'. "\r\n" .
'PRIORITY:5'. "\r\n" .
'BEGIN:VALARM' . "\r\n" .
'TRIGGER:-PT15M' . "\r\n" .
'ACTION:DISPLAY' . "\r\n" .
'DESCRIPTION:Reminder' . "\r\n" .
'END:VALARM' . "\r\n" .
'END:VEVENT'. "\r\n" .
'END:VCALENDAR'. "\r\n";
```

But here the issues is, this is working only with my outlook email ID that means when send the mail it will show on the calendar. if tried to give room (which i created in office 365 admin panel) email ID it is not showing up.

Also I recently cam across with the term called

> Exchange Web Services (EWS)

but I don't have a clue how to start with and integrate in PHP.

Please let me know any suggestion or pointers.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer for this. basically I need to enable set-caledarProccess settings at exchange online.